# Zoom the central image in vertical recycler view

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a vertical scroll view with some effects. I have implemented a vertical scroll view through recycler view and now I  want to find the current item at the center of android device and zoom it.

I have the screen shot attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGRaD.png)

There are numbers of such icons and I want my program to detect which image falls at the central position of layout while scrolling the icons up and down.  so that I could perform some operations on it. I would be really thankful if someone could help me with this.

thanks in advance,

Comment: post what you have `tried` ?

Comment: i have tried using gallery view. but the class was depreciated and adding dependencies created problem in the scroll property.

Comment: https://github.com/flipflopapp/AndroidCustomGalleryView